# how to construct a binary matrix with given row and column distribution

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, graph-theory, coding-theory, combinatorial-designs

I need to construct an $m \times n$ binary matrix $B$ from a given row and columns distribution.
What algorithms can be used for this? As a concrete example : $B$ a $12 \times 63$ matrix with row distribution $12 r^{19}$ and column distribution $12 c^2 + 39 c^3 + 9 c^7 + 3 c^8$. That is
all $12$ rows have weight $19$; $12$ columns have weight $2$, $39$ columns have weight $3$, $\cdots$, $3$ columns have weight $8$. The weight of binary row or column is its sum or equivalently the number of nonzero entries. (This comes up in LDPC code constructions; the example is from [LDPC Code Designs (2017)](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.5555/3137384), page 38)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to use integer linear programming (ILP) as follows.  Let $r_i$ and $c_j$ be the desired row and column sums, respectively.  Let binary decision variable $B_{i,j}$ be the entry in row $i$ and column $j$.  The constraints are
\begin{align}
\sum_j B_{i,j} &= r_i &&\text{for all $i$}\\
\sum_i B_{i,j} &= c_j &&\text{for all $j$}\\
\end{align}
*Branch-and-cut* is the most common algorithm for ILP, but it turns out that for your problem the linear programming relaxation always yields an integer solution.  This particular problem is known as the *transportation problem*, with a supply node for row $i$ and a demand node for column $j$, and the variable $B_{i,j}$ represents the "flow" from node $i$ to node $j$.  Usually the transportation problem has a linear objective function $\sum_{i,j} c_{i,j} B_{i,j}$ to be minimized, but yours is a feasibility problem; you can think of this as taking $c_{i,j}=0$ as the cost.

For your sample data, here is one such matrix:

```
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. ILP seems like a good way to solve the problem. Using matlab's "intlinprog" I get the answer in a few seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very easy way to get the matrix.

First, make $12$ columns of weight $2$. You start from $B_{0,0}$ and color 2 consecutive cells downward in the $C_0$. And the you go to the next column AND the next row ($B_{r+1,c+1}$) and color 2 cells downward from there.

After you're done with the 6th column ($C_5$), you are at the bottom row. And then for the next column, you go back to the top row. And keep going. Luckily, until the $C_{50}$ you can keep doing this way, because both $2$ and $3$ divides $12$. You're done with $12c^2 + 39c^3$ so far.

The problem first happens on the $C_{51}$ where you should color $7$ cells, because you get to the bottom row ($B_{11,51}$)when you colored only $3$ cells. Then you should go to the top row while staying in the same column ($B_{0,51}$). Once you colored all $7$ cells, you go to the next column and the next row. And then you can continue this way until the end.

The below matrix is the outcome of the above procedure.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer; I can see how this would work. Using matlab's ILP was less work than coding the above so I went with that. Interestingly enough the answer looks very similar to what you have (column weight increases from left to right...)